# sql error syntax declare

Tags: mysql, sql

sql error1 here

[image]

sql error2 here

[image]

Comment: declare and set in different line.

Comment: stop posting images .. rather post it as text

Answer (score 2):

Either you should just declare it like

```
declare @startdate date;
```

(Or) set it while declaring like

```
@startdate := DATEFROMPARTS(....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @startdate DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(SYSDATETIME()),1,1)
```

Works fine for me